# Automatically load file from a folder

Tags: php, file-upload

i need like this that it will automatically load file when the file is available in this folder

> templates/order/file

```
<input style="float: right; width: 40%; margin-top: 2px; " type="file" name="zip_images_<?php echo $OrderProduct->orders_products_id?>'[]" />
```

Now i did like this

```
    <?php
if (count($_FILES) > 0)
{
    $objBlockBase->uploadImages($Orderpid, $OrderId);
}

function uploadImages($Orderpid, $OrderId)
{
    $valid_image_type = array('image/jpg', 'image/png');
    $valid_zip_type   = array('application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/download', 'application/zip');
    $folder = DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS . $OrderId . '/block_images';

    (isset($_POST['clearImages']) && ($_POST['clearImages'] == 1 || $_POST['clearImages'] == '1')) ? (exec('rm -rf '.$folder.'/*')) : (true);
    (!is_dir($folder)) ? (mkdir($folder, 0777)) : (true);

    foreach ($_FILES as $file)
    {
        $total_count = count($file['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $total_count; $i++)
        {
            if ($file['error'][$i] == 0 && $file['size'][$i] > 0)
            {
                $str_filename = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.-]", "_", $file['name'][$i]);
                while (strpos($str_filename,"__")>0)
                $str_filename = str_replace("__", "_", $str_filename);

                $file_name = $folder . '/' . $str_filename;
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$i], $file_name);

                if (in_array($file['type'][$i], $valid_image_type) || in_array($file['type'][$i], $valid_zip_type))
                {
                    if (in_array($file['type'][$i], $valid_zip_type))
                    {
                        exec('unzip ' . $file_name . ' -d ' . $folder . '/');
                        unlink($file_name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

It is working only if i upload a file manually. but i want it to load file automatically from templates/order/file. is it possible here?

Comment: You should check the uploaded file, otherwise one could upload a malicious file like a `.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use is PHP's `scandir();` it will supply you with an array of all files inside a folder.

Script example:

`scandir("templates/order/file");`

This will output an array as follows:

```
 Array(
[0] => .
[1] => ..
[2] => test.jpg
[3] => foo.txt
[4] => ex.zip 
)
```

The two dot entries in the array will always appear.

You can also sort the order of the scandir(); before hand. Or actually do almost anything you want with it. Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) for more on the scandir();

I hope this is what you are looking for as it is how I understood your question.

Comment: is it possible to get the file, by searching with the filename i stored in the database?

Comment: Yes you can actually check if file name from your DB is available in the array. `if(in_array("DBFilename", $array)) { echo 'DB file is in folder';}`

Comment: I did it in another way . But thanks for the effort and solution